# Storing dictionary of dictionary in Sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

Suppose I have a dictionary into an another dictionary like-

```
dict={ 'Prem': { 'age' : '23' , 'sex': 'male' } , 'Sameer' : { 'age' : '22' , 'sex' : 'male'} }
```

. How can we store this into Sqlite3 database?

Comment: Note that using only the given name as the primary key will get you into trouble because keys need to be unique, and there is a limited amount of given names.

Answer (score 3):

Relational data is stored in tables. You don't say whether the interior dicts always have the same structure, so for the purposes of this answer I assume they have.

In these circumstances it would be simplest to define a table with three colummns, which I call `name`, `age` and `sex`. The definition would look something like

```
CREATE TABLE t(
    name    VARCHAR(20),
    age     INTEGER,
    sex     CHAR(1))
```

A program to enter your sample data would look something like this:

```
import sqlite3
mydict={'Prem': { 'age': '23' , 'sex': 'male' },
        'Sameer' : { 'age': '22' , 'sex': 'male'}
       } # reformatted to `PEP008` standard, renamed

conn = sqlite3.connect("/tmp/db") # creates a new file if necessary
curs = conn.curs()
for k in mydict:
    curs.execute("""INSERT INTO t (name, age, sex)
                    VALUES (?, ?, ?)""",
                    (k, mydict[k]['age'], mydict[k]['sex'])
conn.commit()
```

This iterates over the keys of `mydict` (I renamed it because `dict`is the name of a built-in type) and inserts the key as `name` and the values of `age` and `sex` from the interior dict.

The `commit()` call is very important - that makes the databases changes permanent!

Answer (score 2):

You could save the dictionary as type `TEXT`, so it would be saved as:

```
"{ 'Prem': { 'age' : '23' , 'sex': 'male' } , 'Sameer' : { 'age' : '22' , 'sex' : 'male'} }"
```

You can save this in the database like this:

```
ogdict = { 'Prem': { 'age' : '23' , 'sex': 'male' } , 'Sameer' : { 'age' : '22' , 'sex' : 'male'} }
c.execute('INSERT INTO tablename VALUES ("{}")'.format(ogdict))
```

And then use the builtin python `eval()` funtion to turn it back into a dictionary:

```
c.execute('SELECT * FROM tablename')
dbdict = eval(c.fetchone()[0])
```

Now, the dictionary from the database is saved in the `dbdict`, and you can use it like a normal dictionary, so calling `dbdict['Prem']` will yield the value of `{'age': '23' , 'sex': 'male'}`.

Answer (score 0):

You need two tables.

First for exmpl Persons:

```
id name
1  Prem  
2  Sameer
...
```

Second stored value:

```
id fk_persons age sex
1  1          23  male
2  2          22  male
```

usualy structure is table for dictionary.

Comment: because name is a key. so it is better to store it elsever.

Comment: Why? There doesn't seem to be any good reason for forcing a join between two tables, since the primary ket will always be indexed anyway,

Comment: For this example yes we can use one table, with unique index over name. But it is better to store keys in other tables, this could improve speed over dml operation

Comment: I understand that integer keys are more efficient for joins, and that many relational users prefer to use integer keys that are under system rather than user-data control, but I still don't see how joining two tables would give a speed improvement over retrieving from a single table. Why do you "need" two tables?

Comment: you won't lose or improve speed having join or select from one table. but you lose it trying to make dml operation over one table then table with key

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it using `df.to_sql()` function from pandas.
I don't know if it's the best way but it works.

```
import pandas as pd 
import sqlite3


your_dict = {
    'Prem': {'age': '23', 'sex': 'male'},
    'Sameer': {'age': '22', 'sex': 'male'}
}

# Transform the dictionary to the desired format
data = [{'name': name, 'age': info['age'], 'sex': info['sex']} for name, info in your_dict.items()]

# Create the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Connect and create SGL database
conn = sqlite3.connect("database.sqlite")
c = conn.cursor()

# Create SQL Table
c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employees (name, age, sex);')

# Write the DataFrame in the SQL database
df.to_sql("database", conn, if_exists="replace", index=False)


# Read the SQL database using pandas
def run_query(query):
    return pd.read_sql_query(query, conn)

query='''
SELECT * FROM database
'''

# Display DataFrame
display(run_query(query))

# After all database operations
conn.close()
```